# Stop make from treating warnings as errors

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, makefile

I'm trying to `make` the little proxy server [`tcproxy`](https://github.com/dccmx/tcproxy):

```
user@localhost:tcproxy $ make
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/Downloads/tcproxy/src'
    CC anet.o
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:25:0,
                 from anet.c:33:
/usr/include/features.h:148:3: error: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Werror=cpp]
 # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'anet.o' failed
make[1]: *** [anet.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/tcproxy/src'
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Compilation is failing because `all warnings are being treated as errors`

It hasn't been updated in two years and it appears the warning is just from something being deprecated, but I'm hoping it should work nonetheless.

I've Googled how to stop all warnings being treated as errors; someone suggests using `-Wno-error` but that made no difference in my case.

How can I force the compilation here?

***Note***

The `Makefile` simply contains:

```
#
# tcproxy - Makefile
#
# Author: dccmx <dccmx@dccmx.com>
#

default: all

.DEFAULT:
    cd src && $(MAKE) $@
```

Comment: It's the compiler that is treating warnings as errors, not make.  Make is merely observing that the compiler says it failed and not continuing because the compilation failed.  So, you'll have to revise the compilation so that the compiler doesn't warn you about the deprecated features.   The warning isn't making life any easier for anyone who has to support multiple versions of multiple systems.

Comment: The relevant makefile is the one in the src directory, not the top-level directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `src/Makefile` there is a line defining :

```
CFLAGS_GEN = -Wall -Werror -g $(CFLAGS)
```

Remove the `-Werror` and the warning you're getting should get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

These are compiler options, not make options, to be clear.

You need to find the options that you use when make invokes your compiler.  Look in your makefile for the option `-Werror`, and remove it from whatever variable it's contained in (probably `CFLAGS` or some variation).